# Leaflet map with coordinates included in the URL path

Tags: leaflet, javascript, coordinates, url

I am trying to implement the dynamic coordinates in the URL path in the leaflet map as per the Google Maps example.

I found some examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919227/get-latitude-longitude-as-per-address-given-for-leaflet

[Dynamically set mapview based on the overlay feature of L.geoJson coordinates in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298226/dynamically-set-mapview-based-on-the-overlay-feature-of-l-geojson-coordinates-in)

from where I tried:

```
    $.when(counties).done(function(){
    var map = L.map('mapid')
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png? 
    access_token={accessToken}', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a 
  href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a   
  href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a     href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 21,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia3J1a2FyaXVzIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2tuaHZqODAxMjYzM28yam40MmpxMmEifQ.3chgJkJajjDBxsF4YHgENA'
}).addTo(map);
```

but my map dissapeared.

Console says:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Is there a way to make my URL dynamic likewise in the BBox case?

http://bboxfinder.com/#0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
https://github.com/aaronr/bboxfinder.com

[image]

Comment: You have a lot of break lines in your code that breaks it ...

Comment: And what you're looking for is called a **permalink**, here's a plugin for leaflet: https://github.com/MarcChasse/leaflet.Permalink

Comment: Thanks, that was a key word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!

```
var mappos = L.Permalink.getMapLocation();
var map = L.map('mapid', {
center: mappos.center,
zoom: mappos.zoom
});
L.Permalink.setup(map);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a   href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a   href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 21,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia3J1a2FyaXVzIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2tuaHZqODAxMjYzM28yam40MmpxMmEifQ.3chgJkJajjDBxsF4YHgENA'
}).addTo(map);
```

Once you enter to the js file leaflet.permalink.js, you can change your default coordinates at the very top (lines 3-6):

```
  getMapLocation: function (zoom, center) {
    'use strict';
    zoom = (zoom || zoom === 0) ? zoom : 16;
    center = (center) ? center : [52.26869, 0.11034];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a simple query string, here is a working example. I took the code below and called it querystring.html, and passes it coordinates  in the url. The maps first view is from N. Adams, MA, and the query string zooms the map to London.

Only issue you have to consider is if the query string is not used, null.

http://localhost/querystring.html?51.5263,-0.0384,51.4836,-0.1414

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>query string</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="mapdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    var map = L.map('mapdiv').setView([42.697765, -73.108005], 14); //N Adams< Mass
    var osm=new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

    var queryString = window.location.search;

        queryString = queryString.substring(1);
        var coords = queryString.split(",");
        map.fitBounds([[coords[0],coords[1]],[coords[2],coords[3]]]); //London

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You used localhost, to which I have no access

Comment: That's just the "server" I put the page on. On a windows PC, start IIS, then put the page  in c:\inetpub\wwwroot which "is" localhost.